# MySQL subquery result with joins and grouping

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble getting mySQL to return the results I am after and therefore hoping someone can give me some pointers on where I am going wrong.  I have 3 tables (Sales_Area, Orders, Rooflight_Request), orders contains a Sales_Area_ID column to join Sales_Area so Sales_Area can have many orders.  Rooflight_Request contains Order_ID so an orders can have many Rooflight_Request.

Rooflight_Request contains the products, I am trying to sum the rooflights total (with equation accounting for price, discount, currency rate and qty) from orders grouping by sales area.

When I run this query:

```
    SELECT salesArea.Area_Name,
(SELECT SUM(((rr.Price - (rr.Price * (rr.Discount /100))) / orders.Currency_Rate) * rr.Quantity) 
    FROM Rooflight_Request AS rr
    WHERE rr.Order_ID = orders.Order_ID
    AND rr.Record_Active = 1 
    AND rr.Alternative_Option <> 1
) AS Rooflights_Total
FROM Sales_Area AS salesArea
    LEFT JOIN Orders AS orders ON
        salesArea.Sales_Area_ID = orders.Sales_Area_ID
    LEFT JOIN Users AS users ON
        salesArea.User_ID = users.User_ID
GROUP BY salesArea.Area_Name
```

The results are grouped by sales area but I am only getting a single orders worth of value.  If I swap the group by to orders.Order_ID the result set then contains all the orders and products but returns thousands of records as it is not grouped by sales area.  Can anyone advise where I am going wrong please?  Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you want to get? A single row per what group ??

Comment: can you add table schema and expected result set it will help others to help you

Comment: The result set I am trying to achieve is one row for each Sales_Area (for example USA and EUROPE) with each row containing a Rooflights_Total amount (which adds up all the rooflights(products) from all the orders attached to that sales area).  With the above query I only get the total from one order.  If I swap the group by to order_ID I then get a row for each order each with its own total.  So I need to add all those orders together and group them under their sales area.

Comment: Hi Mahesh I will go and look into how I can add the schema here as that is not something I have done before.  I had hoped though as we are only talking 3 tables I could explain it.  Sales_Area one to many Orders and Orders one to many Rooflight_Request.  I want the rooflight totals grouped under the salesArea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY THIS ONE IT WILL WORK

SELECT SA.Area_Name ,SUM(((RR.Price - (RR.Price * (RR.Discount /100))) / O.CuRRency_Rate) * RR.Quantity) FROM Sales_Area SA INNER JOIN Orders O ON SA.Sales_Area_ID = O.Sales_Area_ID INNER JOIN Rooflight_Request RR ON RR.Order_ID = O.Order_ID WHERE RR.Record_Active = 1 
        AND RR.Alternative_Option <> 1 GROUP BY SA.Area_Name;

Comment: Fantastic thank you, I put that in and I get the results I am after now I can just add the other parts in using this arrangement, really helpful!

Comment: np if you want any help let me know

Answer (score 1):

looking to you query struct  i think the subselect for total is incorrect .. you should (my opinio) try  joining rr with order to the others tables

```
SELECT  salesArea.Area_Name, SUM(((rr.Price - (rr.Price * (rr.Discount /100))) / orders.Currency_Rate) * rr.Quantity) 
FROM FROM Rooflight_Request AS rr
INNER JOIN Orders ON r.Order_ID = orders.Order_ID
LEFT JOIN Orders AS orders ON
    salesArea.Sales_Area_ID = orders.Sales_Area_ID
LEFT JOIN Users AS users ON
    salesArea.User_ID = users.User_ID
WHERE rr.Record_Active = 1 
    AND rr.Alternative_Option <> 1
GROUP BY salesArea.Area_Name
```

Comment: scaisEdge thank you that is really useful.  The issue now is I simplified the question so I could try and make sense when I was writing it.  I also have other product tables e.g. Extras_Request.  I need the totals from these other tables in the result.  So if I swap the query round to enter into the first product table (Rooflight_Request) I cannot then get the other product totals into the result.  I should have put that in the initial question, I was thinking I could just add those bits in myself after someone helped with the concept.  Of course with this solution that is not the case.

Comment: @scaisEdge Why do you join your results with user table . their is no dependency on that and it will add unwanted join ?

Comment: Hi Mahesh, there are conditions on the user table and a few other tables I was simplifying the part I was stuck to focus on that area.  The answer you have given allows me to put it all in now thanks